# Animated multi-level menu with alpine.js: How can I adjust the max-height of the wrapper when I open the subnav?

Tags: javascript, html, tailwind-css, alpine.js

The problem: The `max-height` of the wrapper does not adjust when I open the subnav. This will make the other links **2.2** and **2.3** disappear.

*Question: How can I adjust the max-height of the wrapper when I open the subnav?*

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/QJan84/pen/yLJaQgJ)

Comment: I realize this question is almost three years old by now, but I ran into this looking for the solution to another - related - issue.

In your codepen, can't you just remove the `overflow-hidden` on line 16?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you don't need to calculate a max-height for your submenus. I tried changing your codepen from

```
x-bind:style="selected == 3 ? 'max-height: ' + $refs.container_3.scrollHeight + 'px' : ''"
```

to

```
x-bind:style="selected == 3 ? 'max-height: 2000px' : ''"
```

and it worked perfectly. I haven't looked cross-browser, but I am doing the same in my drop menu and it's working fine. Since it's just a maximum height and not a calculated height it should work as long as no sub-menu is greater than the number you put in.